# Url Alias not working for domain paths

Tags: drupal-7, alias, pathauto, drupal-domain-access

I'm using domain access module in my website and have multiple domains in my website.  For example I have the domains

1. test.example.com (primary domain)
2. test1.example.com

When I create a sample content "Contact" and provide it with the URL alias as 'contact' (assume node id as 143), Under domain access options I select "send to all affiliates". When I try to access the below url

`test.example.com/contact` (its working fine)
`test1.example.com/contact` (page not found)

But both of these below are working

```
test.example.com/node/143  
test1.example.com/node/143
```

Is it possible to have the same URL alias for all the domains. I used domain path module and its not working as needed.

Thanks.

Comment: you have pathauto installed too?

Comment: Yes i had installed pathauto

Comment: Haven't used that  domain access module actually, but maybe you need to bulk generate the alias in the pathauto conf?

Comment: when creating a content, i was unchecked "Generate automatic URL alias" and manually enter URL alias for some pages.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, what happened to me was, each domain had its own language. I'd turned off multi-lingual support on the content types thinking, "if I select the domain I want the content to appear on, it will default to the domain's language". Wrong!

I found that each node was picking up the default language from /admin/config/regional/language . In this case English. The node's language wasn't displayed anywhere, so I missed it. When I tried to view a page assigned to a French URL, clean URLs just won't work. I could access via the /node/nnn, but not the clean URL.

You need to :

- edit the content type
- in 'Publishing options', 'Multilingual support' set that to enabled.
- save
- edit the content type again
- go to  "Manage Display"
- 'Language' field, set the 'Format' for that to 'Hidden'
- save
- each each node and either set the language to the domains default OR set to 'Language neutral'

Then sit back and watch those URLs work :-)